# How to stop a react-native-video on redirecting to another page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-video

I have a welcome screen which plays a video in the background.  When im redirected to another page i want this video to be stopped.  For playing video i have used [React-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video).

Comment: You can pass a state directive to `<VideoPlayer paused={this.state.pause} />` upon redirecting.